# How to Serialize Sitecore Items from server to local?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, tds

I've installed and setup **TDS (Team Development for Sitecore)** on my solution. My TDS project is now synced in my local sitecore instance and I can now compare my changes, but I am stuck on how can I serialize items from SERVER to LOCAL and vice versa.

I need help with the setup on how to sync my **LOCAL SITECORE ITEMS** to the **SITECORE ITEMS in the server** using TDS and get the changes from the server.

Comment: Would documentation help, like https://hedgehogdevelopment.github.io/tds/chapter4.html#updating-sitecore-items-in-a-project ?

Comment: Removed tags from title; noise reduction; layout.